# cakephp validation to ensure null field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my scenario I have a rest controller that I am validating input data.
I have built a form that I am using purely for custom validation that looks like this:

```
$validator
        ->requirePresence('sport_type')
        ->add('sport_type', 'Require fields missing', [
            'rule' => function ($value) {
                switch ($value) {
                    case 'Football':
                        $this->validator()
                            ->requirePresence('football_id');
                        break;
                    case 'Basketball':
                        $this->validator()
                            ->requirePresence('basketball_id');
                        break;
                    default:

                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        ])
        ->notEmpty('football_id')
        ->notEmpty('basketball_id')

    return $validator;
```

What I need to be able to do, is in the default case, ensure that the other fields are null - if for example, `sport_type = 'Motorsport'`, then the validator must return false if the input data DOES contain something in `football_id` or `basketball_id`.

I cannot see any kind of `requireEmpty` type of method in cake, so can anyone suggest how to accomplish this.  Do I need a separate custom validator for that single rule, and how would I call it from this form validator ?